# I updated the outlook to the latest version but I can't see the ToDo app icon

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I have noticed that some people got the 'MS To Do' app icon in their Outlook desktop app. However, although my Outlook version is updated I still not see it. I use Windows 10. The icon I refer to is shown in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: This has apparently changed to Tasks.  That is how my own Outlook displays and the To Do information I have is sitting in Tasks.

Comment: What's your current view? Would you please provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: Is there any update?